# LHCI - This version of Chrome is too old

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, github-actions, lighthouse

I have set upped the google's lhci to work with my CI from github actions and upload results to a private server.

One issue I got is that the Performance score is "0" or "?" if you open the report.
[image: lighthouse performance score]

The error I receive for the CLS is:

```
This version of Chrome is too old to support 'Cumulative Layout Shift'. Use a newer version to see full results.
```

All I do in the github actions is:

```
npm install @lhci/cli@0.8.x
npx lhci autorun --failOnUploadFailure=true
```

Comment: I have seen this, but was unable to reproduce on a repeat run. It might just be a connection gremlin

Comment: @larowlan found and posted a solution in case you hit the issue again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it turned out the issue was on our self-hosted runner's machine - its `chromium` version was indeed outdated.

But even in this case or in any other as our long term solution will be, always providing a fresh version of chrome through installing `puppeteer`:

```
npm install @lhci/cli@0.8.x
npm install puppeteer
npx lhci autorun --failOnUploadFailure=true
```